# How can I show data in admin panel from DB?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I've followed advice from [How to add custom field in review form opencart 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310320/how-to-add-custom-field-in-review-form-opencart-2?answertab=oldest#tab-top) . So now I can get email in my bd.

But how to show this field in review form below `author` field?

Answer (score 0):

I first suggest you to invest some time in opencart to get some basics at least. And then please share your code first what you tried so far. SO is not a platform to get ready code. However, here is your solution

1.Open your review model `admin\model\catalog\review.php` and find the method `getReviews()`. Now change the query

```
$sql = "SELECT r.review_id, pd.name, r.author. r.user_email, r.rating, r.status, r.date_added FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (r.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";
```

2.Now open the controller `admin\controller\catalog\review.php` file and find the method `getList()`. Here your model has been called to get review. Find

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_review->getReviews($filter_data);
```

Now add an array element for your user email. Add this inside loop

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
 $data['reviews'][] = array(
   ...
   ...
   'user_email' => $result['user_email'],
   ...
   ...

  );
}
```

3.Now open your file `admin\view\template\catalog\review_list.tpl` and add an extra column in your table for user email